# Installing OWASP ZAP as Service on Windows 10

Tags: owasp, zap, yajsw

I am Trying to install OWASP ZAP (2.9.0) to run as a service on one of our servers for the testing environment.   I've been trying unsuccessfully to use YAJSW.  I creates a service but promptly stops running and gives up after a few restarts.   The QA team has selenium tests which are configured to run through the instance of ZAP running on a particular server.  If Zap in manually started.  I would like to just have it running as a background/headless service though.  We use YAJSW to run other java applications as services.  Not sure why this is failing.

Comment: Do you get any error messages, eg in the zap.log file? https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/somethings-not-working-what-should-i-do/#check-the-log-file FYI ZAP is not intended to be run as a long running service, you're better off running it for a specific task and then restarting it for the next one.

Comment: I have been checking the YAJSW logs but hadn't thought to check the zap.log.  I'll take a look thanks.   Maybe I'll spend some time looking at the jenkins plugin and trying to convince the team it's not a fit for a service.